# how to increase the xset rate on mac os?

Tags: macos, unix, vim

I want to increase the speed of the cursor in vim (installed via homebrew, not vi or macvim).
I'm not talking about the motion keys to speed the navigation speed of the programmer, rather the cursor scroll while just hitting `j` and `k` to go up and down.

For linux, as suggested here at http://objectmix.com/editors/149702-cursor-vim-7-0-slow.html#post518421

```
xset r rate 250 75
```

How to achieve this on Mac osx iTerm2 vim ?

Comment: The `xset` sets the keyboard repeat rate and the initial delay. So, exactly this you can achieve with @FDinoff's answer in the System preferences. Check the xset manpage here http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html. The cursor is moving based on keyboard inputs. If want fast cursor moving in the terminal (and vim), change the keyboard repeat rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to in iTerm2 but you can change the keyboard repeat rate from System Preferences.

Go to System Prefrences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard (tab)

Change the Key Repeat Rate to Fast and Change Delay until Repeat to short.